# cURL command is executing without arguments inside docker container

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

`curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information`

getting the above error in docker build.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM curlimages/curl:7.86.0
```

want to setup cURL inside docker container.

Comment: Well did you pass any parameters when you run your image, like showin in the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl)

Answer (score 0):

How to you run `docker build`?

```bash
# from the directory containing Dockerfile
docker build -t mycurl .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM curlimages/curl:7.86.0
7.86.0: Pulling from curlimages/curl
213ec9aee27d: Already exists 
e9574dad2c34: Pull complete 
a2377c20b9b6: Pull complete 
d5ee1ea5a035: Pull complete 
674a88369049: Pull complete 
a5f4f3bb1686: Pull complete 
d097d2aac947: Pull complete 
4a3b312c75a7: Pull complete 
3dc9c808db58: Pull complete 
baca2edfad05: Pull complete 
e3359ad5ca0a: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:cfdeba7f88bb85f6c87f2ec9135115b523a1c24943976a61fbf59c4f2eafd78e
Status: Downloaded newer image for curlimages/curl:7.86.0
 ---> ab35d809acc4
Successfully built ab35d809acc4
Successfully tagged mycurl:latest
```

Then, you can use it just as you would with curl binary:

```bash
docker run -ti mycurl https://www.stackoverflow.com
```